# Trying to run SFML HelloWorld code and i'm getting and error

Tags: c++, dll, linker, runtime-error, sfml

When I run  [this](http://pastebin.com/m619Yj9Y) code I get the error "The program can't start because sfml-window-2.dll is missing from your computer." I linked all the libraries and header files like the tutorial showed me but i'm still getting this error

Comment: Did you copy the .dll files into either your Windows system32/syswWOW64 folder or the folder containing your exe?

Comment: Ya and its still not working

Comment: the mentioned DLL file must be somewhere in the system's search path, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx essentially, either copy it to a folder which is already searched, or add the relevant folder path to the system `PATH` environment variable

Comment: Maybe program is compiled in 64 bits and your dll is 32 bits ? Not sure, its just an idea...

Comment: I am running windows 8 64 bit and the tutorials I was using http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-vc.php was talking about using win32. how would i go about fixing that?

Answer (score 3):

Link SFML staticaly. Use libraries with -s postfix and add SFML_STATIC to defines. I think it's the best way to link SFML on Windows (dll hell!).